# Find gameobject that has increasing number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have few game objects to find that have the names format as "transform_1", "transform_2", "transform_3", etc. so the number always increases. So how do I find the game object when i++ and my gameObject ends with `i`?
Currently, Positions[0] = empty and Positions[1] = transform_1. This is not what I want. How do I make it so that Positions[0] = transform_1 and so on?

```
public GameObject[] Positions;

void Start()
    {
         for(int i=0;i<Positions.Length;i++)
        {
            Positions[i] = GameObject.Find("transform_"+i);
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would expect that to produce a result equivalent to `GameObject.Find("transform_3")` where `i == 3`.

Comment: Thing is, it only captures transform_1 when i=2. How do I resolve this? Such that when I enter Position=3, I get all 3 transform gameObjects instead of only 2.

Comment: code seems OK. Just verify loop is actually running required number of times. What is the value of **Positions.Length** ?

Comment: the problem is you are counting 1-based in your GO naming, but 0 based in your loop. Either change the names of the gameobjects to `transform_0/1/2` or change your for loop to go from 1 to `length + 1`

Comment: I tried ```length + 1``` but I get index out of bounds error. So is there any other solution? I cannot change the naming though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Positions.Length` to `Positions.Length-1`

This is because the script already starts from zero and looping to `Positions.Length` would cause the array to go to long.

The 2nd change is to change
`"transform_"+i` to `"transorm_"+(i-1)"`

This makes it so that the correct game object is selected and cause Positions[0] to equal transform_1